# teachers students database design

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Let's say you have students

and you have teachers

Students log in to the site using a different interface than teachers

Students can do the following on the site
- Look up grades
- Email teachers

Teachers can do the following on the site
- Lookup up students
- Input grades

How would you design the database table to allow teachers and students to log in? This question confuses me because I was thinking of doing the following

- of having a teacher table
- of having a student table

two separate tables

so

create table teacher
(
    name varchar(255),
    email varchar(100),
    password varchar(100)
)

create table student
(
    name varchar(255),
    email varchar(100),
    password varchar(100)
)

Is that how it is usually done? When you have two different entities logging in to two different login interfaces?

--- EDIT ---

also what if the two entities have different fields? Would you still create one Users table with a "Role" in that case.

For example, what if you have the following:

(notice how teacher and student have a few fields different. Would you still create one table to put them both??)

create table teacher
(
    name varchar(255),
    email varchar(100),
    password varchar(100)
    num_of_students int,

)

create table student
(
    name varchar(255),
    email varchar(100),
    password varchar(100),
    gpa decimal(10,2)
)

Comment: Picking up on @Fatal's answer: `create table user ( name varchar(255), email varchar(100), password varchar(100), role varchar(45))`

Comment: @Jorge I would not save the role by its name inside the `User` table. I would have a `User`, `Role` and `User_Role` table. There is a N:M relationship between `User` and `Role` entity. This is what you basically have in every app with role-based security.

Comment: @Fatal Good to know. I have to study database schemas more in depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider just making it one table and add a `TypeID`, where TypeID would classify the type of person be it a student or a teacher.

**Take a look at the design of both of those tables, they are exactly the same, this should be a signal to you that you may be overdoing things.**

By keeping it in 2 separate tables, it is more UI work for you and more administrative work for the person entering the data.

By combining it into one table and introducing a classification or type field you eliminate all that extra work.

`CREATE TABLE Users ( ID int, Type int, name varchar(255), email varchar(100))`

I also would not store the password as plain text, as it appears you may be hinting at with `password varchar(100)`.  `Type` in this case could be an int or even a bit datatype if the only two types of personnel will be Students and Teachers.  The field could be `IsTeacher` with 1 being a teacher and 0 being a student.  But in most cases, you end up realizing you needed a different type of User, hence the `int` datatype.

Comment: "Take a look at the design of both of those tables, they are exactly the same, this should be a signal to you that you may be overdoing things." <- This is what the OP should take away from this exercise.

Comment: also what if the two entities have different fields? Would you still create one Users table with a "Role" in that case.

For example, what if you have the following:
----

create table teacher ( name varchar(255), email varchar(100), password varchar(100) num_of_students int,

)

create table student ( name varchar(255), email varchar(100), password varchar(100), gpa decimal(10,2) )

Answer (score 3):

Designs in most other answers here lack when a user have to be assigned with two "types" or more. In fact, the question is very obviously about users associated with roles which are thenselves associated with rights. And therefore a typical table layout for role-based security is the best in my opinion.

### Entities and Relationship

- User: *John Q. Public*, ...
- Role: *Teacher*, *Student*, ...
- Right: *Look up grades*, *Input grades*, *Look up students*, ...

You've N:M relationship between each:

- User<->Role
- Role<->Right (optional)
- User<->Right (optional)

Maybe checking for roles is enough and you can drop anything with Rights here.

### Solution

Just have a `User` table. (Table: `User`)

*Teacher* and *Student* are `Roles` which Users can be associated with. (Tables: `Role` and `User_Role`)

Another `Role` you typically have in every application is the Role *Admin* which for instance can delete other users, reset passwords, create new users ...

When you've complex rights then you can add `Right`, too. `Right` can be both associated with `User` as well as with `Role`.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a single login table of an ID, email, password as you have, but tack on a flag for TYPE of login... Admin (Site wide), Teacher, Student, whatever.

Then, from the login, you'll have that "type" as a flag to show/hide elments within the site or offer other redirection as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would make one table - `person` and add field `type` to it. Type can be STUDENT or TEACHER for example.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is have a single table called lets say 'users', then a column called 'role' for example, I would then create a script in each interface that will only allow students to login the student interface and teachers in the teachers interface.

To be honest I would actually only have a single permission based user interface, but that is what I would do if I were to use 2 interfaces.

I hope this helps you.